# Popular Modal Bootstrap para Editar Usuário

Tags: php, codeigniter, modal, bootstrap, sql-update

Bom dia, pessoal,

Tenho uma tela de usuário com uma lista que foi populada por um foreach, e cada linha tem um link para editar o usuário. Esse link abre um modal que já deve vir com as informações do usuário, porém estou com dificuldade em fazer isso. Estou usando o CodeIgniter, se alguém puder me dar uma dica...

Comment: O que vc já fez para isso?
Quando vc clica no link, vc passa o id, pega os dados e retorna para o modal?
Eu costumo fazer isso com ajax.

Answer (score 1):

bom muito bem pelo que eu entendi do seu problema é isso aqui você precisa de gera modal de edição para editar usuários, irei publicar um modelo para você seguir como base, está bem simples utilizando apenas php,bootstrap,html e mysql.

dentro da sua lista ou tabela adicione um campo edit e logo depois dentro do seu foreach add esse código aqui que vai basicamente pegar o id de cada usuário e enviar para o seu respectivo modal de edição:

```html
<td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $aqui['login_id']?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
```

logo depois de fazer isso você ira adicional o modal o código a seguir vai criar um modal para cada usuário da sua aplicação para poder alterar os dados, dentro do foreach você irá repedir o mesmo foreach da sua tabela ou lista, aconselho a colocar no final do código mas você que sabe onde coloca o exemplo a seguir é um modal para editar senha:

```html
    <?php foreach($suavariavel as $aqui){ ?>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal<?php echo $aqui['login_id']?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Troca de Senha</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form" method="post" action="user/edicao.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <input id="id" class="form-control" value=" <?php echo $log['login_id']; ?> " name="id" type="hidden">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" required placeholder="Digite uma senha minimo 5 digitos" name="password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button id="ALTERAR" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block " type="submit">ALTERAR</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php  }  ?>
```

depois só receber os dados do modal via post:

```html
<?php
include("banco/banco.php");
    session_start();

// Aqui você se conecta ao banco
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    try{
        $query = "UPDATE login set login_password=:password WHERE login_id = $id";
        $stmt = $conexao_pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
         echo "
  <script type=\"text/javascript\">
   alert(\"Usuario Alterado!\");
   location.href='../usuarios.php';  
  </script>";
    }catch(PDOExecption  $e){
        echo "
  <script type=\"text/javascript\">
   alert(\"Erro, Contate o TI!\");
   location.href='../index.php';  
  </script>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode estar utilizando ajax para popular os campos, talvez isto te ajude:

```
<script>
function pupularModal(id)
{
    var cod_item = id;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/lista/popular_modal",
        type: "POST",
        data: {cod_item: cod_item},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#form_list input").empty(); //limpa os inputs do formulário
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            if (data.status == true) {
                $("#idInput").val(data.value1);
                $("#idInput2").val(data.value2);

                $("#modalId").modal('show');//mostra modal com as informações preenchidas
            } else {
                alert('Erro ao processar')
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function popular_modal()
{
    $cod_lista = $this->input->post('cod_item');

    $item = $this->list_model->get_by($cod_lista);

    if ($item) {

        $data = array(
            'status' => true,
            'value1' => $item->value1,
            'value2' => $item->value2
        );

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

E no botão você usa um `onclick="pupularModal(IdDoItem);"`

Answer (score 0):

Cria um modal genérico, com o id "Model_id_do_usuario" e no botão onde clica para abrir o modal, você passa o link do "Model_id_do_usuario", aí sempre vai abrir o modal daquele usuário! Esse modal fica dentro de um foreach, passando as informações de cada usuário referente aquele id.